# Dictionary where value contains a dictionary and the value contains an array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, data-structures

I have been searching for a while with no success and need an answer.

The data structure I am looking for is a dictionary that have a key and a value. The value is dictionary and have an array as a value.

For example:

```
"San Francisco" -> "Stores", -> "Apple Store", "...", ".." 
                   "Companies" -> "...", ".."
"New York"      -> "Fast Food" -> "Mc", "BK", "KFC"
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried with

```
var nest = [String: [String: [String]]]()
nest["New York"]["Fast Food"] = ["MC", "BK"]
```

This seems to not working properly.

However, I could do this

```
var fastfood = [String: [String]]()
var names = [String]()

fastFood["Fast Food"] = names
nest["New York"] = fastFood
```

This cause problem down the line. I need to create an object each time. I am fetching data from database and need to append the incoming data directly to the nest.

Answer (score 1):

How about to create small data struct that will help you to manage data taxonomy.

Example:

```
struct CityTaxonomy {
    let city: String
    let taxonomy: [String:[String]]
}

CityTaxonomy(city: "San Francisco", taxonomy: ["Stores":["Apple Store", "...", ".."],"Companies":["...", ".."]])
```

Comment: Thats good. I thought that too, but that become a bit complicated when trying to use during fetching. Since fetching is async the "taxonomy" is always empty.

Comment: Please take a look at my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521362/download-multiple-files-containing-data-points-one-file-per-time?noredirect=1#comment74100518_43521362