# Download multiple files containing data points one file per time

Tags: swift

This code works perfectly when downloading one file. However when trying to download multiple files that contain data and caching the incoming data causes a mess. Since the download occurs non-stop, thus one file is done and the next starts. I can't cache them since I don't know which data belongs to which file.

```
lazy var downloadQueue: OperationQueue = {

    var queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1000000
    queue.name = "Files"
    return queue
}()

func fetch(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping ([String:String]) -> (), completionHandlerQueue: OperationQueue?) {

let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data, let type = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8), error == nil else {

            print("Error with the data: \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {

            return
        }

        guard completionHandlerQueue != nil else {
            return
        }
        completionHandlerQueue!.addOperation(BlockOperation(block: {
                completionHandler(type)
            }))
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

// Here is the links

```
let urls = [.....]

func start() {
    for url in urls {
       print("Start")         
       fetch(url: url, completionHandler: { type in

            // The incoming data I don't know which belongs to which url.
       }, completionHandlerQueue: downloadQueue)
    }
    print("End")
}
```

Since its async I will get

```
Start

End
```

Then the data will come. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Why is the `url` variable not available?

Comment: @Mundi Then I would reveal too much.

Comment: You can simply pass `url` in completion closure of `fetch` function and use it in `completionHandler { url, type in`

Comment: Or you could just use the existing url variable. It will be different at every iteration in the loop.